# Syscall param getcwd(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, getcwd

I am testing a program using valgrind for the first time. I haven't found any help regarding this error. What am I doing wrong? how do I solve it?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
   char* dir = "testdir";
   mkdir(dir,0777);
   char* buf = calloc(1, sizeof(char)*255);
   char* directory = realpath(dir, buf);
   printf("%s\n", directory);
   free(buf);
}
```

The valgrind report:

```
==18518== Syscall param getcwd(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==18518==    at 0x4969AF2: getcwd (getcwd.c:78)
==18518==    by 0x48AD520: realpath@@GLIBC_2.3 (canonicalize.c:88)
==18518==    by 0x109216: main (in /home/sol/Documents/SOLProject/.test/a.out)
==18518==  Address 0x4a5013f is 0 bytes after a block of size 255 alloc'd
==18518==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18518==    by 0x1091FF: main (in /home/sol/Documents/SOLProject/.test/a.out)
==18518== 
/home/sol/Documents/SOLProject/.test/testdir
==18518== 
==18518== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18518==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18518==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,279 bytes allocated
==18518== 
==18518== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18518== 
==18518== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==18518== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: The destination string must be at least `PATH_MAX` bytes long. And `PATH_MAX` might be larger than `255`. And on that note, why allocate memory for `buf` dynamically? Also please take some time to study [the `realpath` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) in detail.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not bigger than 255 (it's printed, it's `/home/sol/Documents/SOLProject/.test/testdir`), not the issue here. same goes for dynamic buf allocation.

Comment: The destination ***must*** be at least `PATH_MAX`, as told in the manual page. It doesn't matter that the actual path might be smaller, the buffer itself must still be at least that size.

Comment: Re "*it's not bigger than 255*", Doesn't matter. You are to pass `PATH_MAX` chars. This is clearly the issue since it's failing access the 256th byte ("0 bytes after a block of size 255 [of the block you allocated]")

Comment: ASIDE:  char* dir = "testdir";  ----- should be ----- char dir[] = "testdir";  ----- This is *probably* not causing any issues, but who can be sure?

Comment: @gregspears Can you explain why you think that `char* dir` should be `char dir[]`? Keeping in mind that the first argument of both [`mkdir(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) and [`realpath(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) is a `const char *`.

Comment: Hi @Oka.  In my studies of C I read that the compiler doesn't actually set aside space for the string in declaration char *p="string" but does for char p[]="string";  -- and hence the first method is best abandoned because, although legal I guess, it could bite you sometimes, so I read.  The difference is best illustrated with code, ie: [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9nWs931cc).  -- Please note what happens when you uncomment and attempt the 2nd strcpy() -- code gets a seg fault.    If I've got this all wrong, I would appreciate your kind mentoring -- thanks!

Comment: @Oka - Maybe I've figured this out myself now:  as you pointed out, the arguments of those functions expect a **const** char  pointer.  Hence -- since  testdir *must not* be changed -- this is perhaps the ideal case for usage of the char *p  style of declaration.  Have I understood?

Comment: @gregspears What you have highlighted is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) from attempting to modify the memory associated with a string literal, which is not a problem present in the question. Pointing to a string literal with a `char *` is perfectly valid, given that the *type of* a string literal is `char [N]`. So while nothing *should* be done, `char *dir` and `char dir[]` being equivalent in this program, `const` qualifying the data (as in `const char *dir`) would better show *intent*, and raise warnings if you attempted to modify said data.

Comment: @Oka  -- understood on all.  Thanks very much for taking the time to mentor me on this!

Answer (score 1):

Using hot-off-the-press Valgrind 3.22 on FreeBSD 13.2 I get

```
==12420== Syscall param __realpathat(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==12420==    at 0x4994B1A: ??? (in /lib/libc.so.7)
==12420==    by 0x49CDC16: realpath (in /lib/libc.so.7)
==12420==    by 0x2019D3: main (so12.c:10)
==12420==  Address 0x545f13f is 0 bytes after a block of size 255 alloc'd
==12420==    at 0x4851725: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:1599)
==12420==    by 0x2019C2: main (so12.c:9)
```

As mentioned in the comments, `realpath` expects

```
The resolved_path argument must point to a buffer capable of storing at
least PATH_MAX characters, or be NULL.
```

If I change `realpath` to take NULL for the buffer

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
   char* dir = "testdir";
   mkdir(dir,0777);
   char* directory = realpath(dir, NULL);
   printf("%s\n", directory);
   free(directory);
}
```

then I get no error.